# Scala regex youtube video id

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to extract the video id from a youtube url using the following:

```
val YoutubeRegex = """v=([^&]+)""".r

  "v=IQJ13vFYOU8&feature=g-all-lik" match {
    case YoutubeRegex(videoId) => videoId
    case _ => throw new NoSuchFieldError("impossible to find youtube Id")
  }
```

Saddly this does not work ...  Any ideas ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't that supposed to be like that?

```
val YoutubeRegex = """v=([^&]+).*""".r // need to specify that there could be remainder

"v=IQJ13vFYOU8&feature=g-all-lik" match {
  case YoutubeRegex(videoId) => videoId
  case _ => throw new NoSuchFieldError("impossible to find youtube Id")
}
```

So you will get `IQJ13vFYOU8` part without options.

Comment: that does it, weird I rememeber in F# the regex did not have to be "complete". In any case thanks a lot

Comment: That is difference between find and match. Match should match whole string.